# HTML overlapping text on a nav bar

Tags: html

im trying to get text to overlap the nav bar, when I say overlap I mean expand outside the nav bar white keeping the nav where it is. here is my code I tried using different padding techniques but none have worked. any help would be appreciated :

```css
div {
 padding-top:80px;
}
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin:15px;
 background-color: black;
 line-height: 5px;
}

li {
 float:left;
 font-family: Courier New;
}

li a {
 display: block;
 color: white;
 padding:20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 2px 25px;
}

li a:hover {
 /*background-color: ;*/
 color: white;
}

li a.active {
 background-color: #4CAF50; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Store-1.0.html">Million-Air</a></li>
    <li><a href="men.html">Men</a></li>
    <li><a href="wemon.html">Wemon</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="account.html">Account</a></li>

  </ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out, it was due to the fact I had float left on the li element and it was pushing all the blank space to the left. So I had to use 'clear: both' for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your overflow: hidden property. The text will extend outside the box if you do.

If I am misunderstanding your intent, try linking to what you're trying to do if you have examples online.

Comment: I tried that but it then gets rid of the background colour even though its set to black